# Representation of binary output with douple categories using barplot in r

Tags: r, binary, bar-chart, categorical-data

I am having an exercise to find which signals are more successful for a match at Tinder. I want to represent the results with a barplot that looks like histogram. The output is binary (0 = not match and 1 = match) and the input is categorical (signal = K, N, P and the place = L, S). The data look like this:

```
profil   match   place   signal
 A        1       L      K     
 A        0       L      K     
 A        1       S      P     
 A        0       L      N     
 A        0       L      N     
 A        1       S      N     
 A        0       L      P
```

I am trying to make a barplot  that has at the y axis the total number of matches and at the x axis each signal from each place, like it will be a douple category, the signal K, N, P at L as well as the signal K, N, P at place S. My code is the following but it shows me an error:

```
  ggplot(tinder, aes(factor(place), y= sum(match), fill= signal)) + 
  geom_bar(position= "identity", stat = "identity", beside= TRUE) 
  scale_fill_discrete(name="tinder",
                    breaks=c(1, 2),
                    labels=c("Land", "Stadt"))+
  xlab("Ort")+ylab("Match")
```

Comment: Be sure to include the exact error message you receive in your question.

Comment: I forgot a line the code looks like this:  `ggplot(tinder, aes(factor(ort), y= sum(match), fill= signal)) + 
  geom_bar(position= "identity", stat = "identity", beside= TRUE) 
  scale_fill_discrete(name="tinder",
                    breaks=c(1, 2),
                    labels=c("Land", "Stadt"))+
  xlab("Ort")+ylab("Match")`

Comment: Sure, the error that showed me is :    error in grid.Call.graphics(C_upviewport, as.integer(n)) : 
  cannot pop the top-level viewport ('grid' and 'graphics' output mixed?)
In addition: Warning message:
Ignoring unknown parameters: beside

Comment: Well, `geom_bar()` doesn't have a parameter named `beside=` so it's unclear what your code is trying to do. Maybe you wanted `position="dodge"` instead?

Comment: I have tried it but the plot is giving me that all signals have the equal number of match, which is not the case